# Time complexity of the function multiset_permutations from sympy.utilities.iterables

Tags: python, algorithm, scipy, time-complexity

I'd like to know the time complexity of the function multiset_permutations from SciPy.

We could use this function as:

```
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations
from sympy import factorial
[''.join(i) for i in multiset_permutations('aab')]
```

I'd like to know the time complexity of using this function in comparison to the time complexity of the function permutations from itertools.

I have researched about it in the documentation, but I could not find it.

Comment: You can [measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) the empirical orders of growth, to get a sense of it, to compare between the two.

Answer (score 2):

The classical algorithm looks something like this:

```py
# Enumerates the distinct permutations of seq in lexicographic order.
def multiset_permutations(seq):
    lst = sorted(seq)
    while True:
        yield tuple(lst)
        # Lexicographic order means incrementing the rightmost element that we
        # can. This is the element to the immediate left of the maximal
        # non-increasing suffix. Find it.
        i = len(lst) - 2
        while True:
            # lst is non-increasing, so there are no more permutations.
            if i < 0:
                return
            if lst[i] < lst[i + 1]:
                break
            i -= 1
        # Reverse the maximal non-increasing suffix.
        lst[i + 1 :] = lst[:i:-1]
        j = i + 1
        # Increment lst[i].
        while j < len(lst) - 1:
            if lst[i] < lst[j]:
                break
            j += 1
        lst[i], lst[j] = lst[j], lst[i]


import sympy
import timeit

print(
    timeit.timeit(
        'list(sympy.utilities.iterables.multiset_permutations("aabbccddee"))',
        number=10,
        globals=globals(),
    )
)
print(
    timeit.timeit(
        'list(multiset_permutations("aabbccddee"))',
        number=10,
        globals=globals(),
    )
)
```

sympy…does not do that. I feel for the plight of library developers, but
the sympy routine takes more than three times as long on my machine and
barfs on large inputs. If you don’t need the sympy dependency for
anything else, you don’t have to take it.

It’s straightforward that the routine above runs in time linear in the
total size of the output, Θ(n P) where n is the size of the multiset and
P ≤ n! is the number of multiset permutations.

The best we can say about the sympy routine in general is that it’s
O(n<sup>2</sup> P), contrary to my previous statement. The problem lines
are

```
for j in multiset_permutations(None, size - 1, do):
    if j:
        yield [k] + j
```

By building each permutation with *this* concatenation strategy, spread
across n recursive calls, sympy denies Python the opportunity to do
anything more efficient here (e.g., if the arguments were flipped, maybe
Python can cannibalize `j` somehow). The sympy routine has several
special cases, which avoid this in some cases but definitely not all.
(It’s tedious but straightforward to verify that the rest of the code
for each call runs in time O(n), which given the call stack of size
O(n), is sufficient to prove O(n<sup>2</sup> P).)

(As Kelly points out, the base library’s itertools.permutations is
written in C and uses a reference counting hack to reuse the tuple where
possible, depending the fact that Python code cannot mutate the tuple.
So it’s Ω(n!) and O(n (n!)), with the true running time depending on the
fraction of the time that the calling code forces the tuple to be
copied. The sympy routine both returns lists and is pure Python, so it
cannot do this and is Ω(n (n!)).)

Answer (score 1):

Checking the [source code](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/26f7bdbe3f860e7b4492e102edec2d6b429b5aaf/sympy/utilities/iterables.py#L1278-L1327) of the [sympy 1.11 multiset_permutations](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/iterables.html?#sympy.utilities.iterables.multiset_permutations).

We can see that if you have all unique elements it [yelds from](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/26f7bdbe3f860e7b4492e102edec2d6b429b5aaf/sympy/utilities/iterables.py#L1318-L1319) permutations [imported from itertools](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/26f7bdbe3f860e7b4492e102edec2d6b429b5aaf/sympy/utilities/iterables.py#L2-L5).

So for that case the complexity is the same, but `multiset_permutations` it will add an overhead.

If we take instance the permutations of `abcdegfhij`, it takes ~300ms with `itertools.permutations`, ~700ms with `multiset_permutations`.

However `permutations` does a lot more work. Taking the reference implementation from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

```py
def ref_permutations(iterable, r=None):
    # permutations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BA BC BD CA CB CD DA DB DC
    # permutations(range(3)) --> 012 021 102 120 201 210
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    r = n if r is None else r
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(n))
    cycles = list(range(n, n-r, -1))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
    while n:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            cycles[i] -= 1
            if cycles[i] == 0:
                indices[i:] = indices[i+1:] + indices[i:i+1]
                cycles[i] = n - i
            else:
                j = cycles[i]
                indices[i], indices[-j] = indices[-j], indices[i]
                yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
                break
        else:
            return
```

It is already 40 times slower than the actual `itertools.permutations`.

If you have a list of the frequency of each element, i.e. `n = list(collections.Counter(x).values())` the complexity for `multiset_permutations` is `O(factorial(sum(n)) / prod(factorial(ni) for ni in n))`, while the permutation is `O(factorial(sum(n))`, if `sum(1 for _ in itertools.product(x)) / sum(1 for _ in multiset_permutations(x)) > 100` then `multiset_permutations` should be faster.

But be aware that it the complexity is at least the factorial of the number of distinct elements. If that gets to 15 you are in serious trouble.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. It is not just a wrapper for itertools.permutations. It is algorithmically distinct.  This would the be the equivalent of saying divide and conquer inherits the algorithmic complexity of leaf operations.

Comment: I take that back. Im doing my benchmarking incorrectly. The original benchmark showed that relative scaling of sympy was better than itertools. However, I'm realizing that both are returning generators and iterating on all items isn't being taken into account.

Comment: I think first comment is incorrect. When I told `if you have all unique elements`, I am talking about a particular case where `multiset_permutations` are equivalent, and in that situation `multiset_permutation` takes advantage of `permutations`.

Comment: Of course `multiset_permutation` will be much faster if your argument has many repetitions e.g. `1111111111`.